# Sampling with no replacement in Java from an ArrayList

Tags: java, list, statistics

I have an arrayList with 30 elements. I'd like to create many sublists of 15 elements from this list. What's the efficient way of doing so?

Right now I clone the ArrayList and use remove(random) to do it, but I am sure this is too clumsy. What should I do instead?
Does Java have a "sample" function like in R?

*Clarification*: by sampling with no replacement I mean take *at random* 15 unique elements from the 30 available in the original list. Moreover I want to be able to do this repeatedly.

Comment: Please be more specific.  Are you looking for random subsets, or is there some other criteria?

Comment: what do you mean? you want to create random sublists of 15 items, or all the (unique?) dispositions of 15 items over a set of 30?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [`Collections#shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29) method to shuffle your original list, and return a list with the first 15 elements.

Comment: This is by far the most efficient means of sampling without replacement.

Comment: easiest method by far!

Answer (score 2):

Consider creating new list and adding random elements from current list instead of copying all elements and removing them.

Another way to do this is to create some kind of `View` on top of the current list.

Implement an `Iterator` interface that randomly generates index of element during `next` operation and retrieves element by index from current list.

Comment: but if I generate the index at random when I call next() I don't get unique elements

Comment: yes. The easiest way is to store the previously generated indexes in HashSet.

Answer (score 1):

No, Java does not have a sample function like in R.  However, it is possible to write such a function:

```
// Samples n elements from original, and returns that list
public <T> static List<T> sample(List<T> original, int n) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < original.size(); i++) {
        if (result.size() == n)
            return result;
        if ((n - result.size()) >= (original.size() - i)) {
            result.add(original.get(i));
        } else if (Math.random() < ((double)n / original.size())) {
            result.add(original.get(i));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This function iterates through `original`, and copies the current element to `result` based on a random number, unless we are near enough to the end of `original` to require copying all the remaining elements (the second if statement in the loop).

Comment: I like it, but I am afraid not every element is equally likely to be chosen this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic combinatorics problem. You have 30 elements in your list, and you want to choose 15. If the order matters, you want a permutation, if it doesn't matter, you want a combination.

There are various Java combinatorics samples on the web, and they typically use [combinadics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system). I don't know of any ready made Java libraries, but [Apache Math Commons](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/utilities.html) has binomial coefficient support to help you implement combinadics if you go that route. Once you have a sequence of 15 indices from 0 to 29, I'd suggest creating a read-only iterator that you can read the elements from. That way you won't have to create any new lists or copy any references.